# Multiple Constraint Types or check what type the Generic is?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a Base class that needs a Generic type.  That can be either `EntityObject` or a custom type of mine.
I need a way to constrain the Base class to EITHER type and I also need a way to check if the Generic is of a certain type.
When I do `if (T is EntityObject)` or `if (typeof(T) is EntityObject)` it either says I am using T as a variable, or for `typeof(T)` I get that it "will never be of the given type".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(EntityObject))
```

or

```
if (typeof(EntityObject).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
```

depending on your requirements. (See the docs for [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) for more details.)

Of course, this is an execution-time check - you can't have "one of..." constraints at compile time. Depending on your scenario, it may well be appropriate to have two differently named and constrained public methods which call one unconstrained private method (which "knows" you've got an appropriate type due to only being called from the public ones).

Comment: Will this cover if the 2nd type I want to check on is actually a Base class?  T will actually be "MyObject" but I'll be checking for "MyBase" which MyObject inherits.

Comment: @JamesP.Wright `typeof(MyBase).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))` should return true if `T` is a subclass of `MyBase`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to constrain for two unrelated types.  You either need a common type (like an interface) or two versions of the constrained generic class.

Assuming T is unconstrained, you can use `if (typeof(T).Equals(typeof(EntityObject))) { ... }` to check whether T is of a certain type.